# How do I get Elementor's custom query filter to work with both GET and pagination?

Tags: elementor

I am trying to make a custom filter for the loop grid in Elementor, and am having an issue.  This code lists the items as they should be listed.

```
function my_query_by_filter( $query ) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    $floorplans = '93';
    //$floorplans = $_GET['floorplans'];

    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'layout',
        'value' => $floorplans,
        'compare' => 'in',
    ];

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}

add_action( 'elementor/query/filter_condos', 'my_query_by_filter' );
```

While this code only shows correctly for the first page when using pagination.

```
function my_query_by_filter( $query ) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    //$floorplans = '93';
    $floorplans = $_GET['floorplans'];

    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'layout',
        'value' => $floorplans,
        'compare' => 'in',
    ];

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}

add_action( 'elementor/query/filter_condos', 'my_query_by_filter' );
```

Please also note that this is a simplification of the code to hilight the issue.  My actual code looks like this.

```
function my_query_by_filter( $query ) {
    $start_time = hrtime(false);
    // Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    global $wpdb;
    
//filter based on city
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    echo '<script>console.log("city: ' . $city . '");</script>';
    $floorplans = array();
    $layouts = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT term_id FROM wp_termmeta INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_termmeta.meta_value=wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key="city" AND wp_postmeta.meta_value="' . $city . '" GROUP BY term_id', ARRAY_N);//returns each layout //I will take care of security flaws later
    foreach($layouts as $layout) {
        $floorplans[] = '' . $layout[0];
    }

    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'layout',
        'value' => $floorplans,
        'compare' => 'in',
    ];
    
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    
    $end_time = hrtime(false);
    $execution_time = ($end_time[1] - $start_time[1]);
    echo '<script>console.log("Query took ' . $execution_time . ' nanoseconds to execute");</script>';
}

add_action( 'elementor/query/filter_condos', 'my_query_by_filter' );
```

I am using Elementor Pro and Pods Admin, along with code snippets.

I have tried setting both global and static variables, along with everything that I can think of, but nothing has worked so far.  If there is a better technique to do this, I am open to hearing about it.  I just need the user to be able to filter.